# grafana / prometheus, how to multiply metric value with its label

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Is there a way to multiply the metric value with one of its label value?

```
my_metric{job="job1", instances="2"} = 10
my_metric{job="job1", instances="1"} = 5
my_metric{job="job1", instances="3"} = 10
```

and I want to get the value multiplied by the label instances value

Expected output

```
20
5
30
```

Comment: This is not possible. And hiding a metric in a label runs the risk of having a [cardinality issues](https://www.robustperception.io/cardinality-is-key).

Answer (score 0):

At least this is not possible in Prometheus, but maybe in Grafana. There is the `label_values(metric, label)` function.

So
`my_metric{job="job1", instances="2"} * label_values(my_metric{job="job1", instances="2"}, instance)`
might work, but I did not  test it